# How to disable inlinedit option on list views for a specific profile only?

Tags: apex, administration, list, developer-console, developer

How to disable Custom list view **inline-edit** option for fields for a specific profile ? .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the Profile
Under User permissions -> Mass Edit From List

Comment: even though I have disabled "Mass Edit From List" check box in profile. But still user can edit the fields in list views.